# Grails 3.3.9 - expecting "interface", found '<newline>'

Tags: java, gradle, grails, groovy

I am following the official Grail getting started guide 
https://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/gettingStarted.html to run a hello world application.

However, when I run the command `grails create-app helloworld --profile=web` I got the following error:

```
| Error Error initializing classpath: startup failed:
build file '/Users/sdicola/build.gradle': 3: expecting "interface", found '<newline>' @ line 3, column 20.
   @buildRepositories@
                      ^

1 error
 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
build file '/Users/sdicola/build.gradle': 3: expecting "interface", found '<newline>' @ line 3, column 20.
   @buildRepositories@
                      ^

1 error

| Error Error initializing classpath: startup failed:
build file '/Users/sdicola/build.gradle': 3: expecting "interface", found '<newline>' @ line 3, column 20.
   @buildRepositories@
                      ^

1 error
```

I am using the following SW versions:

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-03-28 09:09:23 UTC
Revision:     f2fae6ba563cfb772c8bc35d31e43c59a5b620c3

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64

| Grails Version: 4.0.0.M2
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_201
```

Comment: @buildRepositories@ remove the last @

Comment: I do not have access to the source

Comment: Can you provide the content of  `/Users/sdicola/build.gradle`

Comment: @Vall0n interestingly if I create a new project in an empty directory I got this:

Comment: C02WW0K9HV2T:gradle-demo sdicola$ grails create-app helloworld
| Error Profile not found for name [web]

Comment: Have a look at [this comment of a grails core bug](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10898#issuecomment-356548131) Maybe that helps to resolve your second issue from the above comment

Answer (score 0):

Per Jeff Brown at [Grails Dev Discuss](https://groups.google.com/g/grails-dev-discuss/c/JG8YH_nnW68?pli=1), I deleted a `grails-app` directory that had gotten created somehow in the directory I was trying to run `create-app` from, and that fixed the problem.